# Assets pipeline when updating to Rails 3.1 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, web-deployment

I've just upgraded my app on Heroku from Rails 3.0 to 3.1, and I'm trying to make the assets pipeline work. The main issue is that I can read from the heroku log the following kind of lines, for every asset:

```
2011-09-03T16:35:28+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/border-a3c571a354b9381740db48aeebfaa63a.jpg] miss
```

If I understand the pipeline correctly, this should not be "miss" for every request I make from a browser, but it should be found in the cache.

Reading the Heroku docs you can find this explanation:

```
Rails 3.1 provides an assets:precompile rake task to allow the compilation penalty to be paid up front rather than each time the asset is requested. If this task exists in your app we will execute it when you push new code.
```

But how should that "assets:precompile" task be? I tried building a project with rails 3.1 from scratch to try to find out, but there is no such task in a bare project. Or am I missing something? How could I make that the assets are found in the cache? Maybe is just an issue with configuration.

These are the options of my production config file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true # If I turn this off I get a 500 error and logs say that an  asset isn't compiled
```

My application.rb has this line:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I compile the assets directly on heroku, not polluting my local repository with compliled assets. 
Use the command : heroku run rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, but here's a tip to help figure out if your assets are live-compiling or not

1. run `rake assets:precompile` locally
2. make some changes to your css but **do not rerun the rake task**
3. git add, commit and push to heroku

If the changes you made in step 2 show up on heroku, then you know your app is live-compiling

Don't forget that you are now in charge of http caching since Varnish is no longer included on celadon, so you need to set up rack-cache and memcached yourself:

- heroku doc on [http caching](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching)
- setup [rack-cache](http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2010/06/24/rack-cache-on-heroku-with-memcached/) with memcached on heroku
- heroku docs on [memcached](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache)

But yeah, I found this puzzling too

Answer (score 5):

Also, take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

> For faster asset precompiles, you can partially load your application
>   by setting **config.assets.initialize_on_precompile** to **false** in
>   config/application.rb, though in that case templates cannot see
>   application objects or methods. **Heroku requires this to be false**

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with `config.serve_static_assets` set to `true` and

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

added to your `config/environments/production.rb` file?

When you push your code to Heroku you should see the precompiling announced by the slug compiler AFAICT.

Comment: "-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline" appears, but so did before. Still getting cache misses though...

Comment: Shouldn't it use the ngnix directive instead?  `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the [Heroku "Cedar" stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack). Then [Heroku will automatically precompile your assets during slug compilation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar).

Note: I'm still getting "cache misses" too, but I don't think that's really true because your app wouldn't work if your assets weren't compiled.

Comment: yes, I have the Cedar stack. If you have "live compilation" activated, it compiles it every time there is a cache miss. Actually, if I deactivate this option (with 'config.assets.compile = true') then it doesn't work at all.